# Bacula search for a file using sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, bacula

I often need to find a file in bacula catalog to restore, but don't know the path or the jobid it was backed up in, nor the full name of the file, just a portion of the name. 
Optimal solution would be an sql search in bacula catalog. I tried all versions of mysql queries inside bconole using sqlquery command of the form:

```
SELECT FROM Filename WHERE Name LIKE '%filename_portion%';
```

but get error on the syntaxis of sql command... 
Any suggestions of the correct sql query format for the task?

thanks
Anton

Comment: Why not use the as-standard-as-possible Bacula interface?

Comment: As the OP mentioned, they do not know the full path- only the portion of the name. Bacula requires a SQL command to do a pattern search.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select *something* in the select statement.  For the filename:

```
SELECT Filename FROM Filename WHERE Name LIKE '%filename_portion%';
```

For the entire record:

```
SELECT * FROM Filename WHERE Name LIKE '%filename_portion%';
```